# Changing the default H1 size in Foundation

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Im trying to change the default font size of my h1,h2,h3 etc. by using the settings file and compiling via SASS.

I've changed the line:

```
 $h1-font-size: rem-calc(44);
```

To:

```
 $h1-font-size: rem-calc(70);
```

But the font size stays the same.

I've removed any other CSS to avoid conflicts. I've also checked the inspector which shows:

```
font-size: rem-calc(70);
```

But it has a strike through.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In Foundation, `rem-calc()` is a SASS function that converts pixels to REMs. If you're seeing `rem-calc` in your processed CSS, your SCSS file didn't get properly processed. You should see something like `1.5rem` in the output CSS file.

Make you sure your SASS file is being processed. If you see other SASS functions in the output CSS file, that's an indication that it has NOT been processed. Whatever processor you're using should give you errors to indicate what part of the SASS file is problematic.